# python scipy fft where is the original function?

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I try to investigate the Scipy fft function to explain how fft work to students.

BUT, the fft function in scipy file is empty ! where is it ? What am I missing ?

When you go to the scipy package directory -> fft -> _basic.py the fft function is this one :

```
def _dispatch(func):
    """
    Function annotation that creates a uarray multimethod from the function
    """
    return generate_multimethod(func, _x_replacer, domain="numpy.scipy.fft")


@_dispatch
def fft(x, n=None, axis=-1, norm=None, overwrite_x=False, workers=None, *,
        plan=None):
    """
    Compute the 1-D discrete Fourier Transform.

    This function computes the 1-D *n*-point discrete Fourier
    Transform (DFT) with the efficient Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)
    algorithm [1]_.

    ...
    a big comment
    ...

    """
    return (Dispatchable(x, np.ndarray),)
```

Where are the lines of code that produce the fft  ?

Comment: it seems it use the numpy fft via the `_dispatch`

Comment: It is likely to be implemented in C rather than python.

Comment: The underlying code is written in C++, in the file [`pocketfft_hdronly.h`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/fft/_pocketfft/pocketfft_hdronly.h). That code is probably not a good introduction to implementing the FFT,  but for an advanced course on numerical computing with C++, it could be very illuminating.